# Esper CEP: Can some one explain "context in esper" with example. And how can i use context with windows and events

Tags: esper, complex-event-processing

Need some explanation in understanding esper context. How can i use esper windows and event with exper context

Comment: Lets say you have a continuous query that gives you just an ascending count of all the events that arrive. That query would be "select count(*) from MyEvent". When you create the query, the engine starts counting and every time a MyEvent events arrives, the engine outputs the current count. When you application stops or destroys the query the engine stops counting. With contexts you can define what starts and stops the analysis such as the counting. With context you can say start counting when XYZ happens and stop counting when N seconds pass, for example.